# C equivalent function

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop, declaration, variable-declaration

I'm working on a task to convert

```
void f(char s[], char t[]){   
    int k=0;
        while (s[k]=t[k])  k++; 
}
```

into the equivalent form of

```
void f(char *s, char *t)
{    
    while (____);
}
```

I know it can be converted to

```
void f(char *s, char *t){
    int k=0;
    while (*(s+k)=*(t+k))k++;
}
```

The problem is, it is only allowed to fill in the bracket. I am running out of idea

Comment: But it's not allowed to add more argument, neither to change while to for

Comment: @fpiette i think the question is invalid at this point? Anyway i edited my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply increment the pointers themselves.

```
void f(char *dest, char *source) {
    while ((*dest++ = *source++));
}
```

This will end the loop when the assigned character is NUL (`'\0'`).

Example program, with type qualifier correctness:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(char *dest, const char *source) {
    while ((*dest++ = *source++));
}

int main(void) {
    char buffer[32];
    const char *string = "Hello, world!";
    f(buffer, string);
    puts(buffer);
}
```

Of course, this has the same issues as the standard library [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy), you must be careful to make sure there is enough space in your destination buffer *before* calling this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
void f(char *s, char *t)
{    
    while (*s++ = *t++);
}
```